# Trying to understand media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a the following 3 media queries set up in my css

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px){
    #main-container{
        width: 375px;
        height: 667px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px){
    #main-container{
        width: 320px;
        height: 568px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px){
    #main-container{
        width: 320px;
        height: 480px;
    }
}
```

When i inspect my page for the appropriate screen the last media query always overrides the dimensions. I am unsure why this is happening, even after the specifying the right max and min widths for that screen

The first media query is for Iphone 6, the second for Iphone 5 and third for Iphone 4

Comment: In which screen resolution do you check this? If you are checking in a screen rsolution of less than480px then the last media query will override.

Comment: i am using chrome toggle mode for device besides that i haven't changed anything

Comment: ok then look for the width, if the width is less than 480px then the last media query will apply because it specifies the range from 320 px to 480px... 
You can also change reslution by entering your custom height and width and then check what happens.... Think you are an investigator..  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The last is overriding the others because the iPhone4 dimensions are between 320px and 480px. Specifically, iPhone4 width is 320px and satisfies the last media query.

So you need to rethink your strategy on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px){
            #main-container{
                width: 320px;
                height: 480px;
            }
        }

```
    Instead of min-device-width and max-device-width:
    use can use:: min-width and max-width

 this should work
```

Comment: check fiddle its working fine .. re-size and check background-color and widths are getting changed..

http://jsfiddle.net/nanduh/z284joyw/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have all those media queries... Why not use 1 media query for mobile...

All your media queries are overriding each other because there defined width's overlap.

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 767px){
    #main-container{
        width: 100%;
    }
}